Can I control a smart Switch from an Alexa skill
I am in research mode, so I have not tried anything, but in my search I am looking to control an existing smart switch from an Alexa skill. Here is my Scenario:

I tell Alexa to "open Spa Max Heat skill"
The "Max Heat skill" does the following

Turns off the pool pump (this is a current smart switch called "pool pump" that I can control with an Alexa device "Alexa turn off pool pump")
Sends a web API request to a separate subsystem that controls the valves for the pool to set them to the appropriate positions to get the max heat for the spa (I already can send a web request from Alexa skill, I have done this in other skills already)
Turn the pool pump back on by sending a command to the smart switch



In my searching, I see the "Alexa Smart Home skill", but that appears to be creating a skill that mimics a smart device ( Alexa command "Turn on MYDevice" invokes the mydevice skill. That is not what I want. I want "Alexa open skill Spa Max Heat" to run my skill that will turn off the pump and then set the valves).
In addition to commanding the switch, I would like to also be able to get the state of the switch, currently from an Alexa device I use "Alexa is the Pool Pump on" to get that information from echo, I would like to get it from within an Alexa skill if possible.

are you asking how to run skill A, then skill B, then skill C in sequence?

Scene is a common name for running a sequence of actions.  A Skill is like an api to provide an interface for a range of devices to Alexa, not just one Scene.
If the scene is created in Alexa, just saying its name runs it. When my scenes are in Fibaro, I just say the name.  Sometimes I say  Run scenename which works as well.
To compare with your scenario, I have a Raspberry Pi at the gate that uses relays to press the buttons on a remote to open the gate. The scene checks a few things, and uses rest calls to the Pi which also does a few things before the gate opens.  I could have just configured it as a scene.  Instead I chose to configure it as a virtual switch.  A normal switch is turned on and off.  It would have sounded weird to say Turn On Gate.
So I gave it the type Blind and called it Gate.   Blinds can be opened.  Now I just say Open Gate. And the virtual switch runs the scene that talks to the Pi.
